# Mitmproxy Client connection killed by block_global

Tags: proxy, mitmproxy

[image]

Installed the latest version of mitmproxy, added cert,  all like in instructions. Proxy not working, can't reach any site...what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 35):

There is an option in mitmproxy called `block_global`: Block connections from globally reachable networks, as defined in the IANA special purpose registries. Default: True

https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-options/

You could try to set this option as false: `mitmdump --set block_global=false`